# CRM 2011 workflow errors before executing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I have a pretty standard workflow setup on our CRM 2011 on prem server. Sometimes the workflow stops with a waiting state before any of the workflow steps are run. The workflow contains some calls to custom workflow activities but the execution doesn't seem to get around to calling them. I have included some screen shots below. Thanks.

[image: Plugin Process]

[image]

Edit: Here is the workflow activity coe as requested.

```cs
public sealed class HandleInspectedIssues : CodeActivity
{
    #region Public Properties
    [RequiredArgument]
    [Input("Inspection")]
    [ReferenceTarget("appointment")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> Inspection { get; set; }

    [Output("Result")]
    public OutArgument<Boolean> Result { get; set; }

    [Output("Errors")]
    public OutArgument<String> Errors { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        #region Workflow Context Setup
        ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

        if (tracingService == null)
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve tracing service.");

        tracingService.Trace("Entered HandleInspectedIssues.Execute(), Activity Instance Id: {0}, Workflow Instance Id: {1}",
            executionContext.ActivityInstanceId,
            executionContext.WorkflowInstanceId);

        // Create the context
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

        if (context == null)
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve workflow context.");

        tracingService.Trace("HandleInspectedIssues.Execute(), Correlation Id: {0}, Initiating User: {1}",
            context.CorrelationId,
            context.InitiatingUserId);

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        Errors.Set(executionContext, String.Empty);
        Result.Set(executionContext, false);
        #endregion

        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        Entity inspection = null;

        tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Inspection Appointment Record: {0}", DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            inspection = service.Retrieve("appointment", Inspection.Get(executionContext).Id, new ColumnSet(true));
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> e)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());

            // Handle the exception.
            throw;
        }

        Int32 inspectionState = Int32.MinValue;
        Int32 inspectionStatus = Int32.MinValue;

        if (inspection.Contains("statecode") && inspection.Attributes["statecode"].GetType() == typeof(OptionSetValue))
        {
            tracingService.Trace("{0}", inspection.FormattedValues["statecode"].ToString());

            inspectionState = ((OptionSetValue)inspection.Attributes["statecode"]).Value;
        }

        if (inspection.Contains("statuscode") && inspection.Attributes["statuscode"].GetType() == typeof(OptionSetValue))
        {
            tracingService.Trace("{0}", inspection.FormattedValues["statuscode"].ToString());

            inspectionStatus = ((OptionSetValue)inspection.Attributes["statuscode"]).Value;
        }

        //Stop processing if the StateCode is not Complete (1) and StatusCode is not Complete (3)
        if (inspectionState != 1 && inspectionStatus != 3)
            throw new Exception("You cannot mark the issues as inspected before the inspection is complete.");

        #region Fetch Query
        string fetchIssues = String.Format(@"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
                                               <entity name='ipm_issue'>
                                                  <attribute name='statecode' />
                                                  <attribute name='statuscode' />
                                                  <attribute name='ipm_issueid' />
                                                  <link-entity name='anhwp_appointmentissue' from='anhwp_issue' to='ipm_issueid' alias='ac'>
                                                    <link-entity name='appointment' from='activityid' to='anhwp_appointment' alias='ad'>
                                                      <filter type='and'>
                                                        <condition attribute='activityid' operator='eq' uitype='appointment' value='{0}' />
                                                      </filter>
                                                    </link-entity>
                                                  </link-entity>
                                               </entity>
                                             </fetch>", inspection.Id);
        #endregion

        tracingService.Trace("Retrieving ipm issue records: {0}", DateTime.Now);

        EntityCollection result = null;

        try
        {
            result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchIssues));
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> e)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());

            // Handle the exception.
            throw;
        }

        tracingService.Trace("Setting ipm issue status to inspected: {0}", DateTime.Now);

        foreach (Entity entity in result.Entities)
        {
            var issueState = entity.Contains("statecode") ? ((OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["statecode"]).Value : default(Int32);
            var issueStatus = entity.Contains("statuscode") ? ((OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["statuscode"]).Value : default(Int32);

            //if the issue is active(0), set status reason to inspected(755390001)
            if (issueState == 0 && issueStatus != 755390001)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("The issue {0} has already been inspected and cannot be inspected again.", entity.Attributes["bdo_issuenumber"].ToString());
                continue;
            }

            var entityToUpdate = new Entity("ipm_issue");

            entityToUpdate["id"] = entity.Id;
            entityToUpdate["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(755390001);

            tracingService.Trace("Updating ipm issue records: {0}", DateTime.Now);

            service.Update(entityToUpdate);
        }

        if (errors.Length > 0)
        {
            Errors.Set(executionContext, errors.ToString());
            Result.Set(executionContext, false);

            return;
        }

        Errors.Set(executionContext, String.Empty);
        Result.Set(executionContext, true);

        tracingService.Trace("Exiting HandleInspectedIssues.Execute(), Correlation Id: {0}", context.CorrelationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to remember that if we didn't set all of the output values to non null values, the Workflow engine had issues.  Do you have any output parameters in the custom workflow activities?

Comment: I do have output parameters and they all get set with at least a default value.

Comment: Can we see your workflow activity code?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code for the workflow activity. The strange thing is that from the details of the workflow error none of the workflow steps have executed.

Comment: your error is happening when CRM attempts to instantiate an Activity.  Why don't you turn on Trace longing to see what it is that is causing this issue.